# What state of matter is Lightening?

Tags: acoustics, plasma-physics, matter, lightning

I know of solid, liquid and gaseous states of matter but what state of matter is lightning? Is it gas, liquid or solid?

Comment: Thunder is a phenomenon arising from sound waves. It is not a tangible object.

Comment: Lightning, on the other hand, is a plasma... "The fourth state of matter".

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Did you mean to ask _What state of matter is lightning?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunder is a sonic boom, generated by the rapid heating of the atmosphere by the lightning discharge.  The heat front moves faster than sound, generating the sonic boom.

Thus what you hear is a pressure wave, and it can be carried by plasma, gas, liquid, or solid: by all of the states of matter.